# How plot and label multiple autocorrelation functions in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, autocorrelation

I have several variables and I want to look at their autocorrelation functions on one graph. I can do this. But the issue is **I am not sure how to create a legend so that I know which variable is which.**

Here is what my data looks like:

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    "Year": [y for y in range(1800, 2000)],
    "Var 1": [random.random() for i in range(200)], 
    "Var 2": [random.random() for i in range(200)], 
    "Var 3": [random.random() for i in range(200)]
})

df.set_index("Year")
```

Now here's how I'd plot the autocorrelation functions on one graph:

```
for variable in df.columns:
    autocorrelation_plot(df[variable])
```

The issue is that there's no legend, so I don't know which variable is which.

Moreover, `autocorrelation_plot` does not have a `legend` argument.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have added a label variable to get the labels:

```
for variable in df.columns:
   ax = autocorrelation_plot(df[variable], label = variable)
```

[Stocks data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSan9.png)

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
for variable in df.columns:
    ax = autocorrelation_plot(df[variable])

ax.legend(ax.get_lines())
```

[autocorrelation_plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#visualization-autocorrelation) returns an object of type `AxesSubplot` which allows you to manipulate the graph like you're used to doing with matplotlib. So to add the legend you just need to pass it as a parameter the lines that the function has just drawn.

For example with this code I print the color of each printed line and I go to change the label of the line, going to add the string `variable`:

```
i=0
for variable in df.columns:
    ax = autocorrelation_plot(df[variable])

    print(variable, ax.get_lines()[-1].get_color())

    for k in range(i, len(ax.get_lines())):
        ax.get_lines()[k].set_label(f'{k}_{variable}')
    i+=6

ax.legend(ax.get_lines())
```

Answer (score 0):

I improvised the answer from @Massifox and I able to have a customized legend for the autocorrelation plot

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
plot_color = []
for variable in df.columns:
    ax = autocorrelation_plot(df[variable])
    plot_color.append((ax.get_lines()[-1].get_color()))

custom_lines = [Line2D([0],[0], color=plot_color [0], lw=2),
                Line2D([0],[0], color=plot_color [1], lw=2),
                Line2D([0],[0], color=plot_color [2], lw=2)]
                
ax.legend(custom_lines, ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'])
```

[Example Autocorrelation Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YERV3.png)