# Plotting multiple Pandas autocorrelation plots in different plots

Tags: python, pandas, plot, autocorrelation

My question is somewhat related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58252736/how-plot-and-label-multiple-autocorrelation-functions-in-pandas). I have a Pandas DataFrame and I want to separately plot the autocorrelation function for `value` each item in `category`. Below is what I've tried, and it plots all of the autocorrelation functions on the same plot. How can I plot them separately and also control plot size?

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'category': ['sav','sav','sav','sav','sav','check','check','check','check','check','cd','cd','cd','cd','cd'],
    'value': [1.2,1.3,1.5,1.7,1.8, 10,13,17,20,25, 7,8,8.5,9,9.3]
})

# Loop through for each item in category and plot autocorrelation function
for cat in df['category'].unique():
    s = df[df['category']==cat]['value']
    s = s.diff().iloc[1:] #First order difference to de-trend
    ax = autocorrelation_plot(s)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to force rendering after each iteration with `plt.show()`:

```
# Loop through for each item in category and plot autocorrelation function
for cat in df['category'].unique():

    # create new figure, play with size
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
    s = df[df['category']==cat]['value']
    s = s.diff().iloc[1:] #First order difference to de-trend
    ax = autocorrelation_plot(s)
    plt.show()  # here
```

Also the syntax can be simplified with `groupby`:

```
for cat, data in df.groupby('category')['value']:
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

    autocorrelation_plot(data.diff().iloc[1:])

    plt.title(cat)
    plt.show()
```